# Deleting User Messages in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord

Is there any way to delete a message sent by anyone other than the bot itself, the documentation seems to indicate that it is possible

> Your own messages could be deleted without any proper permissions. However to delete other people’s messages, you need the proper permissions to do so.

But I can't find a way to target the message to do so in an on_message event trigger, am I missing something or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yup, it should be possible.

You need the bot/user account to have the `Manage Messages` permission.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await message.delete()
```

So, the event would occur something like

```
User sends message
Bot detects that the user has sent a message
Bot deletes the message that the user sent
```

Hopefully from this you should be able to see how user messages are deleted, just ensure that the bot/user account as the `Manage Messages` permission.

Comment: The syntax changed in version 1.0, you need to use `await message.delete()` now. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.delete

Comment: Shouldn't the syntax be `await message.delete()` and not `await message.delete(message)`

Comment: it returns `TypeError: delete() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Answer (score 2):

you can use message.delete() to delete user message.

it's a code if the user sends some curse word to the server so the bot will clean(delete) the message.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    """ some on_message command """
    if message.author.id == bot.user.id:
        return
    msg_content = message.content.lower()

    curseWord = ['curse1', 'curse2']
    
    # delete curse word if match with the list
    if any(word in msg_content for word in curseWord):
        await message.delete()
```

if you are using COG:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(message):
    # rest same as above
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the code you need:

```
@client.command()
async def delete():
    message = ctx.message.id
    await message.delete()
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The delete() should have a ctx paramater and the message=ctx.message.id part should not be there.

Answer (score 1):

if you're trying to delete the last sent message, e.g if a user is calling a command and you want to remove their message and then send the command.
Use this "***await ctx.message.delete()***" at the top of your command, it will find the last sent message and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out a code to delete discord invitations

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg_cnt = message.content.lower()
    if "discord.gg" in msg_cnt:
        await message.delete()
```

So this does that every time a user send something that contains "discord.gg" it deletes it

You can change "discord.gg" whatever you want excepts "***https***", that somehow has given me problems