# Discord Delete Message Prank

Tags: python, discord, bots

So basically in discord.py I wanted to try to prank one of my friends by deleting every message they send. I thought the code would of been simple enough to make but apparently not.

```
 if message.author.id == ("198562028556648448"):
     await message.delete()
```

Comment: Use back-ticks for code blocks, not single quotes.  I'm curious about what kind of help you expect when you show such a small amount of code and do not describe the issue.  Is the code even executed?  For all we know, you're not handling the event correctly to even reach this point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting User Messages in Discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182243/deleting-user-messages-in-discord-py)

Answer (score 3):

According to the Discord [API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.User.id), the message author ID is of type `int`.

It's likely this is the issue, because you can easily demonstrate the non-equivalence of an integer with its string representation in the Python shell:

```
>>> 198562028556648448 == "198562028556648448"
False
```

You should therefore perform your test as follows:

```
if message.author.id == 198562028556648448:
```

Happy pranking.