# Discord.py Delete Reference

Tags: python, discord.py

I wan, that my discord.py bot delete a message, if I answer `p!delete` to a message.
I use this:

```
if message.content.lower() == 'p!delete':
            message = message.reference
            await message.delete()
```

and get this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "FILEPATH", line 303, in on_message
    await message.delete()
AttributeError: 'MessageReference' object has no attribute 'delete'
```

Comment: Why did you do `message = message.reference`?  It is the original message object that has the `delete` method.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182243/deleting-user-messages-in-discord-py

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting User Messages in Discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182243/deleting-user-messages-in-discord-py)

Comment: Not realy. How I get the ID of the reference?

Comment: As you can see in the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=messagereference#discord.MessageReference) you can use `message.reference.message_id` to get the id. You can also try `message.reference.cached_message` to get the message object

Answer (score -1):

the problem is you're overwriting the message object. Here is the improved code

```
if message.content.lower() == 'p!delete':
    await message.reference.delete()
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all, but it now works with this code:

```py
deleteMessage = message.reference.message_id
deleteMessage = await message.channel.fetch_message(deleteMessage)
await deleteMessage.delete()
await message.delete()
```