# Editing a thread with Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am new to python(and new to here too), and I am trying to code a discord bot that stops someone swearing by detecting bad words and deleting his/hers message. It works perfectly at first, with this code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    msg = message.content.lower()

    curseword = ["curseword1","curseword2"]
    
    if any(word in msg for word in curseword):
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention} Do Not Swear')
```

However, when I am testing it in a thread, the bot can't detect the message. What is the problem? Or is it just not possible?
Thanks for your help!

note: this code comes from a reply in [Deleting User Messages in Discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182243/deleting-user-messages-in-discord-py)

Comment: The latest stable release of discord.py 1.7.3 does not support threads yet. Consider upgrading to the 2.0.0 alpha using `pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py`, but please be aware that there are quite a few breaking changes: here https://gist.github.com/apple502j/f75b4f24652f04de85c7084ffd73ec58 and here: https://gist.github.com/Rapptz/6706e1c8f23ac27c98cee4dd985c8120